# Two JavaScript funtions "await" for something that will resolve, is there any way to avoid it?

Tags: javascript, promise

I've to admin I need to read more about this topic. Anyways, here is the background:

1. `foo` and `bar` need to use `instance`, which is a result of a async call
2. `load` is checking if `instance` is `undefined`, to avoid re-loading it

Example:

```
let instance;

// Will resolve in 5 seeconds when instance is undefined
async load() {
  if ('undefined' !== typeof instance) {
    return;
  }

  instance = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    resolve([]);
  }, 5000));
}

async foo() {
  await load();

  // Use instance
}

async bar() {
  await load();

  // Use instance
}
```

Timeline:

- `foo()` will be called after 1 seconds (say **t1**)
- `bar()` will be called after 3 seconds (say **t3**)

Conclusions:

- `load()` will resolve at **t6 (t1 + t5)** for the first time
- `load()` will resolve at **t8 (t3 + t5)** for the second time
- Any call to `load()` after **t6** will return immediately (that's what I want in the first place)
- There is no way to avoid the second `load()`

So to the question: is there any way to avoid the second `load()` (and the second resolve of the promise)? Note that foo and bar will be invoked by a framework, so I cannot "control" their invocation.

**EDIT**: https://www.jonmellman.com/posts/singleton-promises this is the concept of "singleton promises" relative to @Amir question

**EDIT**: looking at the answer (good ones!) this is quite real code of what I'm trying to do. This works as per answer, but it's inconvenient (need to `const instance = await this.load()`):

```
export default class {
  module;

  async load() {
    if (!this.module) {
      this.module = import('amodule').then(({ default: Ctor }) => {    
        return new Ctor();
      });
    }

    return this.module;
  }

  async foo() {
    const instance = await this.load();
  }

  async bar({ params }) {
    const instance = await this.load();
  }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't `if ('undefined' !== typeof instance) {
    return;
  }` be `return instance;`

Comment: How about returning `instance` from the `async load` function. One also might consider turning it into a function which encapsulates `instance`.

Comment: @gremo ... Does the OP create more than one instance from the default exported anonymous class? if not, then there is no need of implementing the module as class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly. You can hold the raw promise and always return it. Once it's in resolve state it, awaiting it will return the value without re-running anything.

```
let promise;

load() {
  if(!promise){
    promise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
      resolve([]);
    }, 5000));
  }

  return promise; // await it outside
}
```

Comment: Check whether `promise` is already defined first (and if so, return it).

Comment: @mbojko - Yup, too much copy paste

Comment: Thanks, seems a good solution indeed. I guess it's not possible without "waiting" for the promise from outside?

Comment: @gremo
Since the operation is an async operation you will need to await the call or add callbacks on the promise using the `then` function. Example: `load.then(r => foo());`

Comment: I see then. The problem of your approach is that i need to `const instance = await this.load()` for each method that needs `instance`. That's why i was setting instance in the first place. In a context of a class, having `this.instance` set is very convenient!

Comment: The problem is your approach. `this.instance` is a static "data" object, but getting that object is via some kind of async operation that takes a couple of seconds. Therefore, a promise needs to be involved in you use case. You can have a promise and it's value in two separate vars, but you always need to check that promise is resolved before touching that var. In your case, calling  `const instance = await this.load()` is equivalent to call `const instance = await promise;`. Creating a function that returns a promise or a value is bad and will not make you code look or function better.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot. This is very useful. I've updated the original question with a real-word example and the problem of getting `instance` in every method. So if I understand correctly, this is the only way to do it right? Because even if i do `this.instance = new Ctor()`, it doesn't change anything in the logic. Need to get into this!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way navigating around a promise/async...await based approach but ...

... from my above comment ...

> *"How about returning `instance` from the `async load` function. One also might consider turning it into a function which encapsulates `instance`."*

```js
const load = (function () {
  let instance;

  return (async function load () {
    if ('undefined' === typeof instance) {

      instance = await (new Promise(resolve =>
        setTimeout(resolve, 3000, [])
      ));
    }
    return instance;
  });
}());

async function foo() {
  const instance = await load();

  console.log('foo ... instance ...', instance)
}
async function bar() {
  const instance = await load();

  console.log('bar ... instance ...', instance)
}

foo(); // 2nd
bar(); // 3rd

setTimeout(bar, 6000); // 5th
setTimeout(bar, 6000); // 6th

setTimeout(() =>
  console.log('(typeof instance) ?..', (typeof instance)), 5000 // 4th
);
console.log('(typeof instance) ?..', (typeof instance)); // 1st
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks. I do like the apporoach of mantaining a local variable/instance but i cannot apply it to a class method (see the original question, edited). Thanks for your time!